# Make a list of text appear in txt block

Tags: c#, wpf, list

What I want is to input a list of text in a text block in C#. Is there a way to do this without having a long string variable as the result text? And make it look kinda like I have written here:

CS Program:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    List<Biltelling> list = new List<Biltelling>();
    int i;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        list.Add(new Biltelling(1,"Personbil",true));
        list.Add(new Biltelling(2,"Lastebil",false));
        list.Add(new Biltelling(3,"Stasjonsvogn",true));
        list.Add(new Biltelling(4,"Varebil",true));
        list.Add(new Biltelling(5,"Buss",false));
        list.Add(new Biltelling(6,"Trailer",false));
        list.Add(new Biltelling(7,"Sportsbil",true));
    }

    private void btnVis_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (i=0; i<list.Count;i++)
        {
            tblResultat.Text = list[i].Resultat();  
        }
    }
```

CS Class file:

```
namespace Biltelling_OOP_The_Edwin_Method
{
    public class Biltelling
    {
    int nummer, antall;
    string type;
    bool størrelse;

    public Biltelling(int inNummer, string inType, bool inLiten)
    {
        nummer = inNummer;
        type = inType;
        størrelse = inLiten;
    }
    public void setAntall(int inAntall)
    {
        antall = inAntall;
    }
    public string Resultat()
    {
        return "" + type + "       " + antall;
    }

    private string småBiler()
    {
        if (størrelse == true)
            return "Småbil";
        else 
            return "Storbil";
    }
}
```

}

I hope that the question came through right...

Comment: are you looking for `string.Join(Environment.NewLine, list.Select(item => item.Resultat())`? Your question is a little unclear as to what you expect the output to be

Comment: The program is going to look like this: http://gyazo.com/671c5c2c23176a149595ea2a3a9b6fdf

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about

```
tblResultat.Text += list[i].Resultat();
```

which would append the `list[i].Resultant()` to the `Text` every time your loop executes.

Another way to do it is

```
tblResultat.Text = string.Join(",", list.Select(bt => bt.Resultant()));
```

Comment: I have used "+=", he has used "=".

Comment: Your answer does not address his comment, "without having a long string variable as the result text"

Comment: Thank you for understanding my stupid quiestion! :D Did not know you could do that to a string, thanks!!

Comment: Ahh, I see you added a better solution!

Comment: Cheers @SindreWilting.. Can you mark that as answer then?